# Как вставить код php в письмо?

Tags: php, html

Внизу код. Это простой скрипт отправки почты. там есть строка "вот ваш секретный код". Я хочу вставить после этих слов rand(30, 100); он должен гененрировать случайные числа. После письмо будет отправляться и получатель будет видеть эти числа. Подскажите, как это сделать? Проблема в отм, что в текст письма у меня не получается вставить php код. Как вставить php код между $message =''; ?

```
$to  = $mail;

$subject = "Заголовок письма";

$message ='
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>Спасибо, что выбрали компанию </title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <p>Вот ваш секретный код:  </p>

          <p>Это сообщение необходимо распечатать.</p>
     </body>
 </html>';

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$code=rand(30, 100);
$message =' <html> <head> <title>Спасибо, что выбрали компанию </title> </head> <body> <p>Вот ваш секретный код: '.$code.'</p>'
```

Comment: Спасибо. помогло!

Comment: может примите ответ?)

Comment: @АлександрТТТ, там галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Не, нима его =)

Comment: чтобы можно было принять ответ нужно по минимуму *15 уважухи*.

Comment: воистину странно... @Shrek это точно?))

Comment: 2 @Ozim угу... у меня такая же штука была когда регился :)

Comment: @Shrek думаю [ты неправ][1]
у юзера 13 очков, и ответ принят =)


  [1]: http://zavu.ru/LAFQEbP/

Answer (score 0):

```
$oldMessage ='<html>
             <head>
               <title>Спасибо, что выбрали компанию </title>
             </head>
             <body>
               <p>Вот ваш секретный код:  </p>
               <p>Это сообщение необходимо распечатать.</p>
             </body>
           </html>';
$messageParts = explode('<p>Это сообщение необходимо распечатать</p>',$oldMessage);
$delimiter ='<p>Это сообщение необходимо распечатать.</p>';
$newMessage = $messageParts[0] . rand(30, 100) . $delimiter . $messageParts[1]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]